# HttpPost ActionResult never fires

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm creating a rest API in .NET Core. I need to do something typically not done via rest: execute a job on a server. After some research I gathered that I should use `[HttpPost]` to do this so I wrote this function:

```
[HttpPost("RunJob/{jobId}")]
public ActionResult<AIXResponse> RunJob(string jobId)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, this function doesn't trigger unless I change `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` In fact, no other verbs work. Only get. Any idea why?

Edit:

Okay this is fixed. I am an idiot was trying to do it through my browser instead of PostMan.

Comment: How are you trying to access this endpoint? If you are using a browser, there's no way that you can access this because, AFAIK a browser always triggers a GET request. And, an HTTP endpoint of type POST wouldn't respond to a GET request..

Comment: So how are you calling this?  What does the client code that initiates the request look like?

Comment: Did you try `Postman` (https://www.getpostman.com/) to make a call to this end-point?

Comment: I lol’d at “typically not done via rest: execute a job...”.

Comment: @RomeoSierra Oh my god. I am embarrassed, It's been a very long day and I was trying to run it through a browser instead of PostMan. Time to call it quits for tonight. Thank you all, I am an idiot.

Comment: Have a good night, @duckwizzle . It happens to us all.

Comment: @duckwizzle, you do not need to write such an update. No body starts with knowledge. I respect that you are trying to learn.